# How to use multiple where varibles in my sql select statement in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Question I have a simple application to query some of my oracle tables I want to be able to grab the value of my text boxes which work but, I keep getting this error any help would be greatly appreciated!

test.py

```
def grabEnts():
   global date 
   connection = cx_Oracle.connect('xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx@x.x.x.x:xxxx/xxx')
   cursor = connection.cursor()
   startdate = e1.get()
   enddate = e2.get()
   #fs = datetime.date(startdate)
   #fe = datetime.date(endate)
   //this works but, I would like to use both startdate and endate
   #cursor.execute("SELECT EMP_ID FROM TO_ENTRIES WHERE LEAVE_START >= '%s'" % startdate)
    //Like this but I can't get it to work I keep getting this error 
    File "test.py", line 62, in grabEnts
   cursor.execute('SELECT EMP_FIRST_NAME FROM TO_ENTRIES WHERE LEAVE_START >=%s AND LEAVE_END <=%s', startdate, enddate)
   TypeError: function takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)

   cursor.execute('SELECT EMP_FIRST_NAME FROM TO_ENTRIES WHERE LEAVE_START >=%s AND LEAVE_END <=%s', startdate, enddate)
   for row in cursor:
       outputent.writerow(row)
   cursor.close()
   connection.close()
```

Comment: How many parameters are you passing to cursor.execute()?  How many does it expect?  What is therefore wrong?  ;-)  By the way, and I can't stress this enough, in general inserting user input directly into SQL opens you up to a so-called SQL injection attack and should therefore be avoided like the plague.  You should instead use parameterized queries.  See here: http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When providing multiple values for a format string, you need to wrap them in parentheses:

```
"My name is %s.  Your name is %s." % ("Sam", "Joe")
```

Comment: Okay so how would I do this then ('SELECT * FROM TO_ENTRIES WHERE LEAVE_START >= %s AND LEAVE_END <= %s' % (startdate, enddate)) because this will not work either ... I get this error NameError: global name 'stardate' is not defined
 @TomKarzes

Comment: I tried it this way as well and got this error     cursor.execute('SELECT EMP_FIRST_NAME FROM TO_ENTRIES WHERE LEAVE_START >=%s AND LEAVE_END <=%s' % ("stardate", "enddate"))
DatabaseError: ORA-00904: "ENDDATE": invalid identifier
@TomKarzes

Comment: Did you type "startdate" or "stardate"?  Make sure you spell it correctly.

Comment: It looks like you're doing the right thing, you just need to type your variable names correctly.

Comment: And no, don't put the variable names in quotes.

Comment: hahah opp's okay that is fixed but now when I enter a startdate for my e1.get and my e2.get text boxes I get this DatabaseError: ORA-00904: "SEP": invalid identifier which for startdate the string would look something like this--> 09-SEP-2015 do I need to convert it to datetime ? @TomKarzes

Comment: You need to do exactly what you did in your original example, with just a single date.  Put the single quotes back around the %s formats.  Copy it exactly, except (1) add the end date and (2) the parentheses.

Comment: So something like this      cursor.execute("SELECT EMP_ID FROM TO_ENTRIES WHERE LEAVE_START >= '%s' AND LEAVE_END <= '%s'" % (startdate, endate))
  @TomKarzes

Answer (score 0):

Using string formatting to generate SQL is general a bad idea. If a user inputs something like `; DROP TABLE blah` this will be executed in your code. This is a typical example of SQL injection...

To avoid, use parameters in your query, like so:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT EMP_FIRST_NAME FROM TO_ENTRIES WHERE LEAVE_START between :start AND :end', {'start': 1, 'end': 10})
```